# How to send attachments from dotnet application to WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have two projects in my solution file one is Webui (a .NET application) and another one is WCF service project.

The scenario is whenever a user uploads a file in Webui, that file needs to be send to the WCF service. Can anyone please suggest me how to send attachments from Webui to the WCF service?

Comment: check this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the file you need to transfer it as a byte stream. You need to use WCF streaming. For example

[how to upload file via WCF](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html)